# Create custom sequence generator in Postgres to consider column value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `jobs` in Postgres, which has columns job_id, username, created_ts and other job related informations. Column `job_id` is of serial type.

```
...
job_id serial NOT NULL,
username character varying(32),
...
```

`username` denotes the user who created the job. An user can only see the jobs which are created by him. He can see the job_id also. This makes the user to see random job_ids, not strictly sequence.

I want to make the sequence start from 1 for each user. It has to be sequential with respect to `username`. This will create duplicate `job_id`s but that's okay.

I have referred https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html I couldn't find any way to create a sequence by column value. Is it possible to create such sequence generator in Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do that with sequences, but unless someone can think of something better, you could remove the sequence and instead have a trigger on INSERT that does something like

`NEW.job_id := COALESCE((SELECT MAX(job_id) FROM jobs WHERE username = NEW.username), 0) + 1;`

As long as you have the appropriate indexes it should be perfectly fast. Though I can foresee issues with concurrency. Depends how you expect to use it.